# Use Intents to choose save file location

Tags: android

What is the best way to ask the user for a location to save a file? Currently, I've managed to get OI File Manager to be used to select a file to load using Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, but I was wondering if there was a way to choose a save location in a similar way?

Answer (score 0):

The following works with OI File Manager:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("org.openintents.action.PICK_FILE");
intent.putExtra("org.openintents.extra.BUTTON_TEXT", "Save");
intent.putExtra("org.openintents.extra.TITLE", "Choose save location");
try {
    startActivityForResult(intent, SAVE_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    //TODO: Handle no save file activity found
}
```

However, I'm not sure if this is the best solution since it uses an OpenIntents action instead of a builtin Android one. How compatible is this between file managers? i.e. does this 
work with all the popular ones like Astro and ES?